# Set values for default address fields in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-nodes

I need to set values for default address fields(langcode, country_code, administrative_area, address_locality ect.) when I create a node. I used below code in the `submitForm` function of a Form class which is extends by `Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase` class. But it not works for me.

```php
$venueNode = Node::create([
    'type'          => 'venue',
    'title'         => 'Venue',
    'field_address' => [
        'country_code'        => 'US',
        'address_line1'       => '1098 Alta Ave',
        'locality'            => 'Mountain View',
        'administrative_area' => 'US-CA',
        'postal_code'         => '94043',
    ],
]);

$venueNode->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake here. There should be a `0` index for `field_address`. Therefore the code should be like below.

```php
$venueNode = Node::create([
    'type'          => 'venue',
    'title'         => 'Venue',
    'field_address' => [
        0 => [
            'country_code'        => 'US',
            'address_line1'       => '1098 Alta Ave',
            'locality'            => 'Mountain View',
            'administrative_area' => 'US-CA',
            'postal_code'         => '94043',
        ],
    ],
]);

$venueNode->save();
```